# Error: Timeout at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17) at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)

Tags: cucumber, appium, webdriver-io

I'm currently working on a test automation project for an Android application. For this, I use the Appium server installed on Node.js as well as the two frameworks WebDriver.io and Cucumber, with the JavaScript programming language.

My project is based on the architecture of features, stages and functions. During testing I had to develop a function with a While Loop that repeats some testing steps. I have tested this loop several times and it works fine. However, the problem with this function is that when this loop needs to run more than twice, the test stops due to a timeout:

Error: Timeout
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)

The problem does not appear to be related to either the locator fault or the loop conditions. So I'm wondering if you can give me the parameter responsible for how long a step takes to execute. According to my analysis, the problem is related to the duration that this step consumes. Despite the fact that this loop has not finished its iterations, the program still stops with this error.

I tried changing these settings, but nothing changes:

capabilities: [{
// capabilities for local Appium web tests on an Android Emulator
platformName: 'Android',
'appium:deviceName': 'Android GoogleAPI Emulator',
'appium:platformVersion': '13.0',
'appium:udid': 'emulator-5554', // emulator-5554 // RZ8RB06WZAL
'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
'appium:orientation': 'PORTRAIT',
'appium:app': join(process.cwd(),'build/ReflexWeb.apk',),
'appium:noReset': true, //Manage application data
'appium:fullReset': false, //To install the app or not
'appium:dontStopAppOnReset': false,
'appium:unicodeKeyboard': true, //To disable the keyboard
'appium:resetKeyboard': true,
'appium:autoGrantPermissions': true, //To force the acceptance of permissions
'appium:newCommandTimeout': 360000,
'appium:adbExecTimeout': 360000000,
}],

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. Can you try updating your npm?
npm update command

That works for me.